# Microsoft Key Storage Provider for Always Encrypted Master Key

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017, always-encrypted, certificate

Hoping someone can help-

I've been experimenting with Always Encrypted columns and have generated a certificate in the "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" -
[image: Always-Encrypted-Auto1]

How can I remove the "Always-Encrypted-Auto1" entry?

using SQL Express 2017 with SQL Management Studio 17.
Have not found an answer to this question via conventional search engine means or via dba.stackexchange.com.

Cheers!

Comment: Explain the down vote?

Comment: While I didn't cast the vote, I guess you received it because of the quality of your question. In [Why is voting important?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) there is a sentence that reads: _"...while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, **or fails to communicate information**."_. (**empasis** mine)

Comment: Without a comment, it's all conjecture, however I've added some clarity to the question so that others in future will know versions and search methods..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I remove the "Always-Encrypted-Auto1" entry?

Since there isn't a way in the SSMS GUI and I doubt you want to write your own code to find out, look in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys` and attempt to figure out based on date which file it may be.

Comment: Thanks Sean, had already tried this earlier this morning but didn't work, tried again and restarted the machine which did work - potentially cached in some way?

Comment: It could have been in cached in memory if it was actively being used by SQL Server. @m.t.bennett